# Do we want an xkcd tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

xkcd is referred to often on PPCG, with at least [47 questions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=xkcd+is%3Aq) which are based on concepts or directly related to the xkcd webcomic.

Therefore, is it worthwhile introducing an [xkcd](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xkcd) tag to group all of these challenges together?

Comment: Don't forget to do it without bumping all of them.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### No

Tags are meant to classify questions according to some distinctive quality that they share. Simply referencing an xkcd comic is not a distinctive quality that would create a meaningful classification.