# Tag proposal: [minecraft]

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags

I'm proposing we create a [minecraft](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) tag for challenges relating to the game [Minecraft](https://minecraft.net).

There are currently 15 applicable questions: [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/170296/minecraft-language-files-updater), [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/48046/how-do-i-craft-that), and [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/45488/nether-portal-detection) just to name a few.

Comment: @Wzl [That's been done](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags?page=8&tab=popular)

Comment: Additionally @Wzl, it's unlikely that this would be about Minecraft the language, and more about challenges that relate somewhat to Minecraft the game (e.g. redstone mechanics)

Comment: I am declining this proposal because it appears that there isn't really much support for this to be created the way proposed here, and a more reasonable interpretation that categorizes challenges where Minecraft is central and not just an inspiration doesn't offer enough challenges to warrant a tag (see caird coinheringaahing's answer). If more challenges arise and there is reason to believe this tag will be helpful, feel free to flag this proposal for reconsideration.

Answer (score 4):

### Yes...

**But only for challenges that relate specifically to features unique to Minecraft, and not challenges that were inspired by Minecraft/Minecraft features**

Minecraft has a system of [commands](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Commands), as well as a method of mimicking electrical circuits via [redstone](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Redstone_Dust). Through these, Minecraft is (close to) [Turing complete](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20219/is-minecraft-turing-complete), and we have answers on the site written in Minecraft. Questions about these systems, such as [Simple Redstone Simulator](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/10588/simple-redstone-simulator) or a [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) for golfing in Minecraft question would be applicable to this tag.

Questions that are inspired by aspects of Minecraft, but that do not relate directly to the coding system of Minecraft should not be tagged with [minecraft](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft). In the same way that a question about printing the [Jelly code page](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/wiki/Code-page) would not be tagged with [jelly](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jelly) as it isn't inherently about Jelly, but a question about a [specific feature](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/216734/66833) of the language would be.

In short, if being about Minecraft is a *central* part of the challenge, not just an inspiration, then it should be tagged with [minecraft](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft).

---

### ...but maybe No

However, I'm not sure how many challenges relate to Minecraft this way. By searching [Minecraft](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=minecraft+is%3Aq), I can only find [one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/10588/simple-redstone-simulator), so I'm not even sure if this tag would be needed.

Answer (score 2):

### No.

For similar reasons to how we [declined](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13161/do-we-want-an-xkcd-tag) the creation of an [xkcd](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xkcd) tag, there is no real classification that arises from having a [minecraft](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) tag. Just looking at the three challenges you linked, one is a parsing / string (YAML to JSON converter) challenge, one is a KC (compression) challenge, and one is a 2D string/grid scanning challenge, and the other ones have similarly unrelated tasks.

Tags are supposed to categorize challenges by some meaningful distinction, which this does not serve.

(Please upvote this to agree and downvote this to disagree. This is not a binding statement, just my opinion and an option to vote for.)